# When back key is pressed from activity it needs to play music again at previous activity

Tags: android

What I want to achieve is to play music when user starts the app, and when user goes to next activity the music stops (this works great). However when user selects back button the audio should start playing again from the main menu (Activity).  Nothing happens now and the music doesn't play at all.

here is my code for MainActivity.java

```
import java.util.List;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MediaPlayer mp;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    super.onResume();
        if(mp != null && !mp.isPlaying())
            mp.start();
        super.onResume();


    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Introduction.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            }

        });
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
 protected void onPause() {
 if (this.isFinishing()){ //basically BACK was pressed from this activity
 mp.stop();
  }
else{

}
 Context context = getApplicationContext();
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
 if (!taskInfo.isEmpty()) {
 ComponentName topActivity = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity; 
 if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
  mp.stop();

}
else {
    mp.stop();
 }
}
   super.onPause();

 }
}
```

And here is my code for Introduction.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Introduction extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.introduction);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

}
}
```

Should I add something in the introduction class or not?
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

you have a mess friend you call super.onResumen inside onCreate.

try to override onResumen and put all your staff there:

```
@Override 
public void onResumen(){
super.onResume();
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audio);
mp.setLooping(true);

    if(mp != null && !mp.isPlaying())
        mp.start();

}
```

becouse onResumen is call every time the activity comes to foreground again

Answer (score 0):

Since you're starting the Introduction activity with `startActivityForResult()`, in MainActivy.java, override the method `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`.  Inside this method, you can start the music again.

```
@Override onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if(mp != null && !mp.isPlaying())
        mp.start();
}
```